# PHP If first result in grouped MySQL array

Tags: php

I'm selecting a recordset from MySQL which is grouped by release_date using `$group_date`. 
What I need to do is calculate whether it is the first iteration of `$group_date` and output different HTML compared to if it isn't the first iteration of `$group_date`.

The different HTML is as simple as not outputting the first `echo '</div>';` in the code below.

I've tried variations of `$i=1 and $i++` but I can't seem to get it working as all the code examples i've found are based on normal results, not when they've been grouped.

```
<?php
 while( $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
 if ($group_date !== substr($row["release_date"], 0, 10)) {
 $group_date = substr($row["release_date"], 0, 10);
 echo '</div>';
echo $title == "" ? "" : $title;
$title = "";
echo '<div class="divide-bottom">';
echo '<h3>' . $group_date . '</h3>';
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update - this seems to work fine for me:

```
<?php
$iteration = 0;
 while( $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
 if ($group_date !== substr($row["release_date"], 0, 10)) {
 $group_date = substr($row["release_date"], 0, 10);

 if ($iteration == 0) {
echo $title == "" ? "" : $title;
$title = "";
echo '<div class="divide-bottom">';
echo '<h3>' . $group_date . '</h3>';
$iteration++;
}
else {
     echo '</div>';
echo $title == "" ? "" : $title;
$title = "";
echo '<div class="divide-bottom">';
echo '<h3>' . $group_date . '</h3>';  
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try that

```
   if ($group_date != substr($row["release_date"], 0, 10)) {
```

Comment: Sorry, i'm not sure where i'm putting this code? Or am I just taking one of the equals signs off my current code?

Answer (score 0):

```
$iteration = 0;
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $release_date = substr($row["release_date"], 0, 10);

    if ($group_date == $releaseDate && $iteration == 0) {
        echo '<h3>' . $group_date . '</h3>';
        $iteration++;
    }

    echo '<div>' . $title . '</div>';
    echo '<div class="divide-bottom">';
}
```

Comment: This seems to be using multiple variables that haven't been defined? `$releaseDate` and `$group_date`